# Como transformar objeto de email em Stream, Buffer ou String?

Tags: node.js, email, parser, imap

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de emails e meu servidor está sendo feito em HapiJS, e estou tendo problemas em pegar o email e transformá-lo em uma String, Buffer ou Stream.

Quero transformar para esses formatos porque são somente esses que o [MailParser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/) aceita, porém estou com algumas dificuldades.

Primeiramente eu consegui fazer tudo certo, mas para isso eu estava criando arquivos TXT e depois fazia a leitura deles, e em ambas as etapas utilizava o fs. Porém quero pegar os emails e fazer o parse deles sem criar nenhum arquivo, utilizando Buffers, Streams ou String que fiquem em memória até o parse ser concluído.

Já estou lendo a documentação do NodeJS, do MailParser e do [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap)(que estou usando para pegar os emails, porém ainda não consegui resolver esse problema...

Comment: Como assim **pegar os emails**? de onde esta recebendo? de uma requisição, do disco, outro stream?

Comment: Estou recebendo eles de uma conta de testes que criei no gmail, usando o node-imap, ele faz a conexão e após configurar as variáveis com login e senha ele busca os emails e dá pra filtrá-los através das flags, porém, para conseguir exibir esses emails na minha aplicação preciso fazer o parse(com o MailParser) e preciso fornecer como entrada para o parse uma String, um Buffer ou uma Stream, e quero fazer isso sem criar arquivos no disco, somente guardá-los em memória no decorrer do processo. E não estou conseguindo transformar o email em nenhuma das três opções que citei acima...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o o **objeto** do email for literalmente um `object` javascript (em memória) podes converte-lo em `string` usando `JSON` e então usar `Buffer`:

```
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

let object_example = {
    test: true
}
// convert to string
let mailBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(object_test), 'utf-8')
// as a Promise
simpleParser(mailBuffer).then(mail=>{}).catch(err=>{})
```

Como estas buscando com `node-imap` e "filtrando" logo acredito (por não ter usado **node-imap**) que estes retornos (resultados) sejam em memória (`arrays` ou `object` unitários). Basta usar a lógica acima, apenas substitua **"object_example"** pelo item retornado por `node-imap`.

Caso o retorno de `node-imap` seja uma matriz deves percorre-lo.